# Can I give the C++ header file using Pimpl or do I have to flatten with C built-in types?

Tags: c++

We have a proprietary C++ library, I was thinking giving the **C++ header file using the Pimpl idiom** and the **shared library file .so**.

Nevertheless, I found this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/portability-at-abi-boundaries-modern-cpp?view=msvc-160

> Class types can only be used when caller and callee agree on layout,
> calling convention, etc. That's only possible when both are compiled
> with the same compiler and compiler settings.

I understand that quote as "my lib's users will have to use the same compiler with the same compiler's settings".

- How portable is my shared library with its Pimpl C++ header file? (I use gcc8, c++14)
- What should I do to compile the shared library so that all my users will be able to compile their application? compatible with old and new ABIs, with gcc/clang and any C++ version?

Comment: Alternative is to provide C-API ("C" shared dll), and provide (inline) wrappers around the C-calls.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you for the very fast answer, looks like it's the easiest solution. I'll go for it!

Comment: From everything I've read, I still should be fine if I compile with stdc++11 and any gcc>=5.1 and clang compilers. The users will still be able to compile with anything and >=C++11 (c++23 doesn't seem to have an ABI break)

Comment: Dependencies (as standard), might have different possible compilation options which break ABI (extra member in Debug (visual has iterator checks)). So you have to read carefully your compiler spec/doc about that.

Comment: mmh I see, I'll keep reading a lot about that. It seems there are several reasons that could lead to an ABI break. The C++ version, the compiler, the compiler's version...